# Ansible vars using lookups

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that populates some variables, here is a snippet:

```
#myTest playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: False
  vars:
    - APP_NAME: "{{lookup( 'env', 'name')| mandatory }}"
```

I'd like to use another lookup first, and take that value if its been populated. Is this achievable in one line? I'm figuring something like Javascript's `||`:

```
- APP_NAME: "{{lookup( 'env', 'customName') || lookup( 'env', 'name')| mandatory }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) with an option to trigger it if the value of the preceding expression is an empty string (as in the case of an undefined environment variable):

```
- APP_NAME: "{{ lookup('env', 'customName') | default(lookup('env', 'name'), true) | mandatory }}"
```